# How to store cache data inside WEB-INF Directory in Production for Grails?

Tags: war, ehcache, grails-3.1

I am using cache and ehcache plugin. I have configured ehcahe.xml as follow

```
<ehcache name="backEndData">
<diskStore path="user.dir/src/main/webapp/cache"/>

  <defaultCache
      maxElementsInMemory="0"
      maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
      eternal="false"
      overflowToDisk="true">
  </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

It is working in development environment perfectly but how to make this working after deploying war file.

Comment: Why would you want to use WEB-INF directory? Why not a location on disk that is well known and can be configured?

Comment: I am deploying my application in aws server. so is it possible ?

Comment: I do not know the answer to that question.

Comment: I am also having problem while storing cached data in disk on development mode too, cached data is not stored in .data file but .index file have some encoded value. .index file is only created after i shutdown the application. can you provide me some solution ?